# Crash app when renderInContext multiple time

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview

I've spent a lot of time in Google searching but I have not got good result.
I convert UIWebView to PDF, a webview with long contentsize (ContentSize of scroll in webview).

I used RenderInContext for loop but it make crash when I convert with webview has long
Please help me to fix this bug with 20 page.

This is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(documentDirectoryFilename, CGRectMake(0, 0, aWebView.scrollView.contentSize.width, screenHight), nil);
aWebView.scrollView.contentSize.width, screenHight), nil);

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [[[aWebView subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, screenHight * i) animated:NO];
        [aWebView.layer renderInContext:currentContext];
        currentContext = nil;
    }

}
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
aWebView.layer.contents = nil;
```

I used autoReleasePool and saved result to file. but it produces crash too.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code i used tested that works fine for me…

```
 -(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIWebView*)webView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
    {
        NSString *heightStr = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"];

        int height = [heightStr intValue];
        //  CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        //  CGFloat screenHeight = (self.contentWebView.hidden)?screenRect.size.width:screenRect.size.height;
        CGFloat screenHeight = webView.bounds.size.height;
        int pages = ceil(height / screenHeight);

        NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, webView.bounds, nil);
        CGRect frame = [webView frame];
        for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
            // Check to screenHeight if page draws more than the height of the UIWebView
            if ((i+1) * screenHeight  > height) {
                CGRect f = [webView frame];
                f.size.height -= (((i+1) * screenHeight) - height);
                [webView setFrame: f];
            }

            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
            CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            //      CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 72, 72); // Translate for 1" margins

            [[[webView subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, screenHeight * i) animated:NO];
            [webView.layer renderInContext:currentContext];
        }

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
        // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
        NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

        NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

        // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
        [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
        [webView setFrame:frame];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code is same my code. If you renderInContext in for loop within 20 time. It make your app crash. I make sure I tested more time with above code

What I know is that renderInContext not release memory in the loop. The big question in here is How can I release context after use renderInContext for once time ? I used ARC and tried to use : CGContextRelease(currentContext). But it can not work

Other best idea ? Help me please